# move attribute to parent

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to restructure some HTML using XSLT. How can I transform this:

```
<div>
    <h2 class="foo">...</h2>
    <p>bar</p>
</div>
```

into:

```
<div class="foo">
    <h2>...</h2>
    <p>bar</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your intent is clear but the previous commenter is right - you forgot to show your current XSLT code or inform us about what did not work.

Comment: @PhilVallone: I've tried a few different things, but I'm stumbling in the dark, really. I'm going to check out the answer below - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using XSLT 1.0, the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="div">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:value-of select="h2/@class"/>
      </xsl:attribute> 
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="h2/@class"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input has the output

```
<div class="foo">
 <h2>...</h2>
 <p>bar</p>
</div>
```

The first template `<xsl:template match="@*|node()">`is an [identity transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) - matching all attributes and other nodes, copying them and applying the identiy transformation to all child nodes and attributes of the current context node.

The empty template `<xsl:template match="h2/@class"/>` removes the `class` attribute from the `h2`, while the template matching the `div` copies the `div` and adds the `class` attribute of the `h2` using

```
<xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:value-of select="h2/@class"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

If you're using XSLT 2.0, this could be adjusted to

```
<xsl:attribute name="class" select="h2/@class"/>
```